# saveRDS in a pipe %>% and have it return the object

Tags: r, magrittr

Is there a way to use saveRDS in a pipe `%>%` chain?

```
c(1,2,3) %>% 
saveRDS(file="123.rda") %>% 
mean()
```

This currently gives an error because saveRDS returns null.

**I want saveRDS() to return c(1,2,3)!**

Comment: What is `mean()` doing in your code?

Comment: Pipes pass the output of one function into the next. What do you expect to be the output of `saveRDS`?

Comment: `c(1,2,3) %>% 
  saveRDS(file="123.rda")` This works right?

Comment: I want saveRDS to simply return the object.

Comment: `saveRSD` saves the object to your current working directory (unless you specify another location). If you want to work with the object again you either need to refer to the original object (if it is still in your workspace), or you could use `readRDS(file="123.rda")` to get the object again (assign it or pipe out of it). I would not reccomend piping out of `readRDS` but it is certainly possible.

Comment: I am aware of the behavior and how saveRDS works. I want an alternative like save_pipe() which saves the object but also returns the object as a side effect.

Comment: Add that info as an edit to your question. Or edit / clarify your question.

Comment: There's an implementation, can't test it: https://rdrr.io/cran/tfse/src/R/read-save-rds.R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `tee` (`%T>`) operator from `magrittr`

```
library(magrittr)
1:3 %T>% 
   saveRDS(file="123.rda") %>%
   mean
#[1] 2
```

If we wants to return the same object, use `I`

```
1:3 %T>% 
  saveRDS(file="123.rda") %>%
  I
#[1] 1 2 3
```

---

According to `?"%T>%"`

> Pipe a value forward into a function- or call expression and return the original value instead of theresult. This is useful when an expression is used for its side-effect, say plotting or printing.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe write your own function which behaves as per your expectation

```
save_and_return_RDS <- function(x) {
   saveRDS(x, file="123.rda")
   return(x)
}
```

and then use it

```
c(1, 2, 3) %>% save_and_return_RDS()
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: @JohnWaller maybe, I am not sure but didn't took much time to write my own.

Answer (score 2):

Use `save_RDS` in the `tsfe` package! It returns an invisible object you can use in a pipe.

```
c(1,2,3) %>% 
tfse::save_RDS("x.rda") %>% 
mean()

# returns 2
```

Comment: this answer was provided by @NelsonGon in the comments

Comment: `write_rds` from `readr`, exported in `tidyverse`, does this as well